# Quartz scheduler in not running in war

Tags: gwt, jboss, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler in gwt web application.My application structure is like below.

I have two project.One is gwt web application client project(for ui part) & other is java  project for server side call.(for database interaction).In client project I put a server project for reference.While running I create a war from client and add a jar of server project to war folder.

Now I used scheduler at server side for some task to auto complete.While running it locally (with out war) scheduler working properly.

But while running war at jboss server scheduler is not running.

My all scheduler related code and Quartz.jar is at server side.There is no any reference of Quartz in client side project.is this the problem???

Here is my code for scheduler

```
public class QuartzJob implements Job {

public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext)
        throws JobExecutionException {
    JobDataMap map = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
    ActivityTransactionSettingsMap map2 = (ActivityTransactionSettingsMap) map
            .get("task");

    if (map2.getAutoCompleteDate() != null) {
        WorkFlowFacade facade = new WorkFlowFacade();
        facade.completeAutoCompleteTask(map2);
        Scheduler scheduler=(Scheduler) map.get("scheduler");
        try {
            scheduler.shutdown();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    JobDataMap map2 = new JobDataMap();
    map2.put("task", actsMap);
    map2.put("scheduler", scheduler);
    JobDetail job = newJob(QuartzJob.class).withIdentity("job"+String.valueOf(actsMap.getId()))
            .usingJobData(map2).build();
    Trigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger"+String.valueOf(actsMap.getId()))
            .startAt(actsMap.getAutoCompleteDate()).build();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Or do I need to shift my scheduler related project at client side only??
I am not getting how to solve this.
Please help me out

Comment: The scheduler has nothing to do with your GWT code as far as I can see it . What is the trigger for the scheduler?

Comment: Here is the trigger. Trigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger") .startAt(tomaroDate).build();

Comment: Not sure I get you here. Should it start running continuously from the next day ? Is this what you need ?

Comment: it is just a sample...it will start on an particular date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the scheduler to run , there should be something to kick start it . I am not sure how the process is happening but you could write this scheduler in a servlet

```
public class MySchedulerServlet extends GenericServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1477091380142883153L;

/**
 * Constant to represent property for the cron expression.
 */
private static final String CRON_EXPRESSION = "0 0 0 ? * SUN";

public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {

    super.init(servletConfig);

    // The Quartz Scheduler
    Scheduler scheduler = null;

    try {

        // Initiate a Schedule Factory
        SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        // Retrieve a scheduler from schedule factory
        scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        // Initiate JobDetail with job name, job group and
        // executable job class
        JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("RetryJob", "RetryGroup", QuartzJob.class);
        // Initiate CronTrigger with its name and group name
        CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger("cronTrigger",
                "triggerGroup");
        // setup CronExpression
        CronExpression cexp = new CronExpression(CRON_EXPRESSION);
        // Assign the CronExpression to CronTrigger
        cronTrigger.setCronExpression(cexp);
        // schedule a job with JobDetail and Trigger
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTrigger);

        // start the scheduler
        scheduler.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void service(ServletRequest serveletRequest,
        ServletResponse servletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

}
```

and in your web.xml load sceduler on startup. This works for me.

```
       <servlet>
    <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

        <servlet-name>MySchedulerServlet </servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.servlet.MySchedulerServlet </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used thread in this case.

```
public class AutoCompleteTaskThread extends Thread {

private ActivityTransactionSettingsMap taskMap;

public AutoCompleteTaskThread(ActivityTransactionSettingsMap map) {
    this.taskMap = map;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        new AutoCompleteTaskScheduler().ScheduleJob(taskMap);
    } catch (Exception e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

As below and in local machine it is working fine.but for jboss server it is not working.

Comment: Again the question , Who is calling the start method of the thread ?

Answer (score 0):

I used an instance of AutoCompleteTaskThread class and called start method on this.

```
    private void addAutoCompleteTask(ActivityTransactionSettingsMap newTask) {
    AutoCompleteTaskThread thread = new AutoCompleteTaskThread(newTask);
    thread.start();
}
```

Here for I started a thread for any new task for which I want to start new thread.